# Perl autoincrement of string not working as before

Tags: perl, auto-increment

I have some code where I am converting some data elements in a flat file.  I save the old:new values to a hash which is written to a file at the end of processing.  On subsequence execution, I reload into a hash so I can reuse previously converted values on additional data files.  I also save the last conversion value so if I encounter an unconverted value, I can assign it a new converted value and add it to the hash.

I had used this code before (back in Feb) on six files with no issues.  I have a variable that is set to ZCKL0 (last character is a zero) which is retrieved from a file holding the last used value.  I apply the increment operator 
...
$data{$olddata} = ++$dataseed;
...
and the resultant value in $dataseed is 1 instead of ZCKL1.  The original starting seed value was ZAAA0.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6):

Do you use the `$dataseed` variable in a numeric context in your code?

From [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement):

> If you increment a variable that is
>   numeric, or that has ever been used in
>   a numeric context, you get a normal
>   increment. If, however, the variable
>   has been used in only string contexts
>   since it was set, and has a value that
>   is not the empty string and matches
>   the pattern /^[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*\z/ , the
>   increment is done as a string,
>   preserving each character within its
>   range.

Comment: ++, Good candidates would be comparison using numeric operators like ==, <, >= instead of eq, lt, ge, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As prevously mentioned, ++ on strings is "magic" in that it operates differently based on the content of the string and the context in which the string is used.

To illustrate the problem and assuming:

```
my $s='ZCL0';
```

then

```
print ++$s;
```

will print:

```
ZCL1
```

while

```
$s+=0; print ++$s;
```

prints

```
1
```

NB: In other popular programming languages, the ++ is legal for numeric values only.

Using non-intuitive, "magic" features of Perl is discouraged as they lead to confusing and possibly unsupportable code.

Comment: *intuitive*  ≡  *familiar*  ≡   *previously‐encountered*

Comment: Right! And if you're familiar with it in other programming languages, ++ on strings is non-intuitive. ;)

Comment: Are you suggesting he reimplements alpha ++ because you're not familiar with it?

Comment: Not at all. I'm suggesting that using ++ on strings can make your code confusing--as it relies on special non-intuitive "magic"--and that doing so might impede someone else's understanding of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this almost as succinctly without relying on the magic `++` behavior:

```
s/(\d+)$/ $1 + 1 /e
```

The `e` flag makes it an expression substitution.

Comment: He's also incrementing letters. ZAAA0 became ZCKL0

Comment: Doesn't answer the problem as stated. As ikegami noted, OP needs to inc letters as well.